# Re-style Login Form Whilst Keeping CSS Separate from Frontend CSS

Tags: functions, wp-login-form

I'm changing the appearance of the WP login page for a client and I'm using CSS in addition to the following code in my functions.php file.

```
// CUSTOMIZE LOGIN SCREEN
add_filter('login_headerurl', 'ourHeaderUrl');

function ourHeaderUrl(){
  return esc_url(home_url( '/' ));
}

// enqueue CSS into the login page
add_filter('login_enqueue_scripts', 'ourLoginCSS');

function ourLoginCSS(){
  wp_enqueue_style('main_styles', get_stylesheet_uri(), array(), '1', 'all');
}
```

These functions use the stylesheet from the frontend, thus adding more CSS to my frontend CSS file. Is there any way of styling this page by keeping the CSS separate from my frontend CSS?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Just make it clear.

Comment: @MaxYudin Why have you down-voted this? It's perfectly clear in my question what I wish to achieve - "Is there any way of styling this page by keeping the CSS separate from my frontend CSS?" I don't wish to add extra CSS to my frontend style.css file.

Comment: "Is there any way of styling this page by keeping the CSS separate from my frontend CSS?" - Yes. Just create another .css file and `wp_enqueue_style()` this separate file instead of your main style.css

Comment: @kero - that will still be pulled into the frontend though?

Comment: When some people unable to read the rules of the WPSE I have to downvote to make them read the rules. CSS is not a part of WordPress!

Comment: @MaxYudin It's not a CSS question. It's a question about how to enqueue styles in the back end only (which hopefully includes the login page). Please upvote the question again.

Comment: @TheChewy Why would it be pulled into the frontend? Via calling `wp_enqueue_style()` you explicitly say, which files should wen be loaded. As long as you don't enqueue the login styles on the frontend, WP won't automagically do it

Answer (score 0):

You can enqueue styles for the login page with [login_enqueue_scripts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/login_enqueue_scripts).

Example:

```
function themeslug_enqueue_style() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'loginStyles', 'login-style.css', false ); 
}

add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'themeslug_enqueue_style', 10 );
```

Comment: OP is already using that hook. And will `'style.css'` really work the way it is intended?

Comment: So will I then have the login CSS in a separate CSS file which will replace 'style.css' in the above code? And will I have to enqueue this separately as well?

Comment: I edited the example to maybe make more sense.  Create a file called login-styles.css and but only the login related CSS in it and enqueue it like the example.

Comment: This didn't work I'm afraid. It shows an error message in the console for my site on Chrome that says `GET http://localhost:8888/mysitelogin-style.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)` The path in this message seems to be missing a forward-slash before the 'login-style.css' part at the end?

Comment: It’s looking for the file in the root of your site, change the path to where your css file is